# unicorn, capistrano install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, capistrano, unicorn

I have the following **deploy.rb**

```
# RVM bootstrap
# $:.unshift(File.expand_path("/home/tim/.rvm/lib"))
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))
require 'rvm/capistrano'
set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.2'
set :rvm_type, :user

# bundler bootstrap
require 'bundler/capistrano'

# main details
set :application, "polco"
role :web, "13.213.13.94"
role :app, "13.213.13.94"
role :db, "13.213.13.94", :primary => true
set :rails_env, "production"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
set :deploy_to, "/home/passenger/cba"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :user, "passenger"
set :use_sudo, false

# repo details
set :scm, :git
set :scm_username, "tbbooher"
set :repository, "git@github.com:tbbooher/foo.git"
set :branch, "master"
set :git_enable_submodules, 1
set :keep_releases, 5

# # server details
set :unicorn_pid, "#{shared_path}/pids/unicorn.pid"

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup"

namespace :unicorn do
  desc "start unicorn"
  task :start, :roles => :app, :except => {:no_release => true} do
    run "cd #{current_path} && bundle exec unicorn_exec start"
  end
  desc "stop unicorn"
  task :stop, :roles => :app, :except => {:no_release => true} do
    run "#{current_path}/bundle exec unicorn_exec stop"
  end
  desc "unicorn reload"
  task :reload, :roles => :app, :except => {:no_release => true} do
    run "#{current_path}/bundle exec unicorn_exec reload"
  end
  desc "graceful stop unicorn"
  task :graceful_stop, :roles => :app, :except => {:no_release => true} do
    run "#{try_sudo} kill -s QUIT `cat #{unicorn_pid}`"
  end
  desc "restart unicorn"
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => {:no_release => true} do
    run "#{current_path}/bundle exec ./unicorn_exec restart"
  end

  after "deploy:restart", "unicorn:restart"
end

after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:config_symlink"
# hope this works
before "deploy:restart", "deploy:fix_file_permissions"

namespace :deploy do

  task :config_symlink do
    run "ln -s #{shared_path}/application.yml #{release_path}/config/application.yml"
    run "ln -s #{shared_path}/mongoid.yml #{release_path}/config/mongoid.yml"
    run "ln -s #{shared_path}/mailserver_setting.rb #{release_path}/config/mailserver_setting.rb"
    run "ln -s #{shared_path}/omniauth_settings.rb #{release_path}/config/omniauth_settings.rb"
  end

  desc "Fix file permissions"
  task :fix_file_permissions do
    run "chmod a+x #{current_path}/unicorn_exec"
  end
end

namespace :deploy do
  task :restart do
  end
end
```

and the following bash script, **%rails_root%unicorn_exec**

```
#! /bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          unicorn
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: starts the unicorn web server
# Description:       starts unicorn
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/home/passenger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/unicorn_rails
DAEMON_OPTS="-c /home/passenger/cba/current/config/unicorn_tacitus.rb -E production -D"


NAME=unicorn_rails
DESC=unicorn_rails
PID=/home/passenger/cba/shared/pids/unicorn.pid

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo -n "Starting $DESC: "
    $DAEMON $DAEMON_OPTS
    echo "$NAME."
    ;;
  stop)
    echo -n "Stopping $DESC: "
        kill -QUIT `cat $PID`
    echo "$NAME."
    ;;
  restart)
    echo -n "Restarting $DESC: "
        kill -QUIT `cat $PID`
    sleep 1
    $DAEMON $DAEMON_OPTS
    echo "$NAME."
    ;;
  reload)
        echo -n "Reloading $DESC configuration: "
        kill -HUP `cat $PID`
        echo "$NAME."
        ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $NAME {start|stop|restart|reload}" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Which uses the following config: **config/unicorn_tacitus.rb**

```
worker_processes 2
base_dir = "/home/passenger/cba/current"
shared_path = "/home/passenger/cba/shared"
working_directory base_dir

preload_app true

# we destroy all workers who are taking too long
timeout 30

# This is where we specify the socket.
# We will point the upstream Nginx module to this socket later on
listen "/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock", :backlog => 64

pid "#{shared_path}/pids/unicorn.pid"

# Set the path of the log files inside the log folder of the testapp
stderr_path "#{shared_path}/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "#{shared_path}/log/unicorn.stdout.log"

before_fork do |server, worker|
# This option works in together with preload_app true setting
# What is does is prevent the master process from holding
# the database connection
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
# Here we are establishing the connection after forking worker
# processes
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

I'm getting the error below on cap deploy. How should I be calling unicorn_exec to restart? It looks like bundle exec doesn't run. In general, I'm looking for feedback on my whole process, since I am new to mongodb, unicorn and nginx and sure there is at least one thing I am doing non-optimally.

```
executing "/home/passenger/cba/current/bundle exec ./unicorn_exec restart"
    servers: ["16.213.39.23"]
    [16.213.39.23] executing command
 ** [out :: 16.213.39.23] bash: /home/passenger/cba/current/bundle: No such file or directory
    command finished in 613ms
failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell '1.9.2' -c '/home/passenger/cba/current/bundle exec ./unicorn_exec restart'" on 16.223.39.23
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't take a look at your entire setup, but I think I know what's causing that particular error.

Look you have this:

```
desc "start unicorn"
task :start, :roles => :app, :except => {:no_release => true} do
  run "cd #{current_path} && bundle exec unicorn_exec start"
end
```

which is the correct way to call bundle as far as I know, but then your other tasks do this:

```
desc "stop unicorn"
task :stop, :roles => :app, :except => {:no_release => true} do
  run "#{current_path}/bundle exec unicorn_exec stop"
end
```

So notice that in this case, your `run` call isn't formatted the same way. Go to `unicorn:stop`, `unicorn:reload`, and `unicorn:restart` tasks and change the:

```
#{current_path}/bundle
```

part to

```
cd #{current_path} && bundle
```

So that the end result looks like this:

```
run "cd #{current_path} && bundle exec unicorn_exec <whatever the command is>"
```

Comment: Excellent. Appreciate your insight, it works now. Still worried that I am breaking the convention set by wiser coders, but it is working now.